# Android ads with admob doesn't show when i'm using Mobile Data

Tags: android, admob, ads

i'm using Android google play services com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest to show ads on my app but it's only working on wifi network and not with mobile data .

is it normal behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be a connection issue. When connected to `WiFi`, you'll be able to get the ad in a relatively short amount of time, whereas with mobile data it will exceed the 5 second limit to load an ad and it times-out. However, even if it fails, the `AdRequest` will restart the request and try to show it up again, but it will depend on the user's mobile data strenght.

Comment: what is the solution for it? I have tested in 4G data still same issue